# равны ли все значения в массиве PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив со структурой -

```
$arrays = array(0 => array('baks' => 5),1 => array('baks' => 8), 2 => array('baks' => 10), 3 => array('baks' => 15));
```

Он может выглядить как

```
$arrays = array(0 => array('baks' => 5),1 => array('baks' => 5), 2 => array('baks' => 5), 3 => array('baks' => 5), 4 => array('baks' => 5), 5 => array('baks' => 5));
```

Как понять пришел ли массив `$arrays` с равными значениями или нет?

Comment: Пройтись по нему и проверить значения.

Comment: @Arendach а где у тебя появился array2?

Comment: Понял, надо проверить сами значения а не массив

Comment: @u_mulder ну так подскажите как пройтись по нему так чтобы сравнить все элементы между собой, а то я пока не придумал. Был вариант использовать for сurrent и next где потом current записывался как last, только вот проблема как потом последний сравнить с первым. если например их будет 10 элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно это подойдет

```
$arrays = array(0 => array('baks' => 5),1 => array('baks' => 5), 2 => array('baks' => 5), 3 => array('baks' => 5), 4 => array('baks' => 5), 5 => array('baks' => 5));

function check ($array) {
    // здесь от условий задачи, если передан пустой массив или 
    // с одним елементом
    if (count($array) <= 1) return false;

    // тянем первый элемент массива и с ним сравниваем остальные
    $first = array_shift($array);

    foreach($array as $item){
        if ($item != $first) return false;
    }

    return true;
}

var_dump(check($arrays)); // bool true
```

**UPD:** без функции

```
$arrays = array(0 => array('baks' => 5),1 => array('baks' => 5), 2 => array('baks' => 5), 3 => array('baks' => 5), 4 => array('baks' => 5), 5 => array('baks' => 5));

$equal = true;

$first = array_shift($array);
foreach($array as $item) if ($item != $first) $equal = false;

var_dump($equal); // bool true
```

Comment: Это я так понял нулевой индекс ты сравниваешь с последующими? этого получается достаточно

Comment: ну да так и есть

Comment: А я что то себе усложнил пошел через форы...

Comment: надеюсь ответил на вопрос